# Indexing of matrix elements

Tags: matrices

In matrices the element  $a_{11}$ represents the element in the 1st row and 1st column. What does the element  $a_{123}$ represent? Does it represent the element in 1st row 23rd column or the element in 12th row 3rd column??? What is the correct form to write it?

Comment: Usually, there should be a $,$ between the row and the column. For example: the element in the $20$th row and the $10$th column will be represented by $a_{20,10}$

Comment: Can you show some context? Normally, one wouldn't write $a_{123}$. If there's every some ambiguity, you could just write $a_{1,23}$ for the first case or $a_{12,3}$ for the second.

Comment: Are you asking about tensors?